# Validation of data posted in Talend esb

Tags: talend, esb

I'm working on a route in Talend that should interogate an api and store the resulting data in a queue.

I have issues with the request to have 2 validations of data posted on api.

One of them is to have only digits and commas in string posted and
the second is to have at most 200 numbers (ex: 123,34,35,780,01, ..... to have no more than 200 numbers between commas

A colleague suggest to use regular expresions and I found this expression `^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$` for doing the first demand but I do not know how to use it in my route.

I use cREST and I do not know where to put this expression for doing the validation.

Can you help me?

Thanks,

Aurel

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity is to put a cMessageRouter component after the cREST component.  You can then pull a 'when trigger' and enter a predicate that will be evaluated to conditionally send the message to your queue. Assuming that your API returns a raw string (in which case you should make sure to set the Accept-Type of the cREST component to 'any') and using the Simple language, the
predicate could look like `"${body} regex '[your regex]'"`.  If the predicate evaluates to false, you can pull an 'otherwise trigger' from the cMessageRouter to send the message to a dead-letter queue, as shown below.

Note that you can have the cMessageRouter component evaluate multiple predicates and send the message to different destinations depending on the condition that is fulfilled.

[image: Example of using cMessageRouter to conditionally route API responses]

Answer (score 0):

To access the exchange in a bean, add the following import `import org.apache.camel.Exchange` and set the first parameter of your bean method to be of class Exchange, as in `public static Integer yourMethod(Exchange exch) {}`.

Documentation at [https://camel.apache.org/manual/bean-binding.html].

Comment: Thank you , but how I call this method? From when trigger I have the condition context.no_of_products >= beans.CountProducts.noOfProducts() with bean type of language . How I call this method from when trigger to pass the exchange value to the bean? Probably there is a syntax to pass the exchange , TIA

Comment: I've found exchange variable in simple expression language and I updated the when trigger to be simple language and the condition to be                  context.no_of_products >= beans.CountProducts.noOfProducts(exchange) but without luck ... I do not understand why